# Getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) when printing elements of an array (Using pthreads)

Tags: c, pthreads, dynamic-arrays

So I'm trying to use threads (Using pthread) to do bucket sort. The program tries sorts 3500 integers that go from 0 to 999 and divides them in ranges (This ranges depend on the number of threads) so if there are 4 threads one thread will sort the numbers from 0 to 250, another thread will sort from 251 to 500 and so on.

I tried to make a function that returns an array that contains only the numbers in the range of each thread. That's the function that I send as an argument in pthread_create. This is the code for that function and the global variables:

```
int arreglo[3500];  //Array of 3500 random numbers
int elementosEnArregloTmp;  //Number of elements in each range
int num_Hilos;          //Number of threads
int elementos_Arreglo = 3500;   //3500
int tamanoRango;     //Size of range. 1000 / #OfThreads

    int *llenarElementosArreglo(int A[], int n){        
        int i,k=0;
        int *B = malloc(sizeof(int)*A[n]);
    for(i = 0; i < 3500; i++){
        if(n < num_Hilos-1){
            if(arreglo[i] >= tamanoRango*n && arreglo[i] < tamanoRango*(n+1)){
                B[k]=arreglo[i];
                k++;
            }
        }
        else if(arreglo[i] >= tamanoRango*n && arreglo[i] < 1000){
                B[k]=arreglo[i];
                k++;
            }
    }

    mostrarArreglo(B,A[n]); //Funcion que imprime el arreglo
    elementosEnArregloTmp = A[n];
    
    return B;
}
```

With this function I try to create a dynamic array with the size of the elements that the main array of 3500 integers had in each specific range (That's what the array A[] is for) and 'n' is the thread that the function is going to return the array with the elements in range.

When I run the program with only 1, 2 or 3 Threads I have no problem, it runs perfectly, but when I put 4 Threads or more I end up getting a segmentation fault (core dumped). I have also noted that the segmentation fault doesn't happen when filling the dynamic array, but instead happens when calling the function at the end (mostrarArreglo) which prints the elements of the array.

I've been trying to change some things for hours but I haven't been able to solve this.

I'm also going to put some part of the main code, though I don't think the problem is within the main code.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){  
    ...
    ...
    pthread_t hilos[num_Hilos];     //Se declara que habran 5 hilos

    for(i = 0; i < num_Hilos; i++){ //Ciclo para crear los 5 hilos con su funcion que sera bucketSortPorHilo
            error = pthread_create(&hilos[i], NULL, bucketSortPorHilo, (void*)(llenarElementosArreglo(elementosPorRango,i)));     
            if(error){          
                    fprintf(stderr,"Error %d: %s\n", error, strerror (error));
                    exit (-1);
            }
            error = pthread_join(hilos[i], NULL);
            if(error) error_fatal(error, "pthread_join");
        }  
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: 'int *B = malloc(sizeof(int)*A[n]);'  this looks off.  printf out A[n] here - is that a sane value for tbe number of ints?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have printed A[n] and it does have the same value for the number of integers in that specific range!! The thing I find really weird is that the program works for 3 or less threads and when using more threads it works up to some threads and prints, after that I get the segmentation fault.

Comment: 'elementosPorRango' where is it declared and defined?  Have an upvote anyway for actually checking a value I was suspicious about.  It's actually rare to get actual feedback:)

Comment: Thanks!! And 'elementosPorRango' is defined in a part at the beginning of the main code, that part of the main code I didn't put here because it's just a lot of printf and stuff like that, that's why I only showed the part with the for where I create the threads!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know if it's wrong to answer my own post, but the way I solved this was returning a struct that contained the array (Of each range of numbers) and an int with the number of elements of the array!!